# Laravel: debug screen is not showing after upgraded from 5.4 to 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I upgraded my app from Laravel 5.4 to 5.5. And now when I enter a wrong URL, instead of showing me the debug page for not found exception, it shows me a beautiful 404 page with the text "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." This is similar to the situation when you run your application on a production env having `APP_DEBUG=false` in the `.env` file. But here I have set `APP_DEBUG=true` and `APP_ENV=local` on my local env.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: check your app/exceptions\handler.php, and see what settings you have there,

Comment: Are you running `artisan serve` to test this or is this served by a dedicated HTTP server (nginx, Apache, etc)? I'm asking because if you're using the `serve` command the `.env` vars are loaded only once when running the command, and you'd need to rerun the command to pick up `.env` changes.

Comment: @pseudoanime No one stores their settings in the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class. The settings are stored in `config/app.php` and in the `.env` file.

Comment: @Bogdan No, I use Laravel Valet.

Comment: @Debiprasad, I know, duh!. I mean the setting for handling the exceptions.

Comment: do a `php artisan config:clear` and a `view:clear`

Comment: can you share the variable that you have shared above `APP_DEBUG=true` i wanna see what have you set before this one

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi No, it did not solve the issue.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I am sorry, I can't understand what do you ask. Could you please rephrase this?

Comment: can you share the content write above `APP_DEBUG=true`?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo It's `APP_KEY`.

Comment: does it have space? @Debiprasad

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo No

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I think `php artisan config:clear` and a `php artisan view:clear` might have solved the issue. I am not sure whether it did or something else. I was using a 404 page to check whether I got the debug page (Whoops page) back or not. Now I understood that Laravel 5.5 does not throw NotFoundHttpException, thanks to Adre Astrian. Now I can see other exceptions producing the Whoops page.

Comment: @Debiprasad basically IOC container was working based on old caching config file. I have provided with an answer which I think solved ur issue ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel does some caching on its IOC container so make sure to clear the config cache:

`php artisan config:clear`

and just for the sake of it run

```
php artisan view:clear
```

then finally set your new config cache by :

```
php artisan cache:config
```

The file itself can be found in `bootstrap/cache/config.php`

Comment: in laravel 5.8 i'm getting:
` Command "cache:config" is not defined.

  Did you mean one of these?
      cache:clear
      cache:forget
      cache:table
`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.5 now includes the error pages for various HTTP status codes including 404. And uses those error pages if you don't have any custom error pages.

If you check the `laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\views` folder you'll get those error pages. And these were absent in the v5.4.

You can check the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#http-exceptions) to customize the 404 page for your need.

When Laravel throws `NotFoundHttpException` exception it's being handled by the render method in `App\Exceptions\Handler` class. Then depending on the exception, a response is being prepared here. And for this particular exception, Laravel prepares response using the 404 error view file.

For example, if you remove the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exception‌​s\views\404.blade‌​.ph‌​p` file you'll get the exception and stack trace displayed by whoops. Provided that you don't have `resources\views\errors\404.blade.php` file too.

So if you want to catch the `NotFoundHttpException` exception you can do this from the `render` method in `App\Exceptions\Handler` class:

```
if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
    throw $exception;
} else {
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: But it has nothing to do with Custom HTTP Error Pages.

Comment: When Laravel throws `NotFoundHttpException` exception it's being handled by the `render` method in `App\Exceptions\Handler` class.

Then depending on the exception a response is being prepared here. And for this particular exception Laravel prepares response using the 404 error view file located in the answer.

So yes, it has everything to do with the error pages.

Comment: For example, if you remove the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\views\404.blade.php` file you'll get the exception and stack trace displayed by whoops.

Provided that you don't have `resources\views\errors\404.blade.php` file too.

Comment: I am unable to see the debug page (whoops page) while I have set `debug` to `true`. All I see a friendly error page (vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\views\404.blade.php in case of a 404 error and some other page in case of other errors). I hope you understand my issue now.

Comment: Just to be clear, if you remove the 404 blade file you get the whoops page, or not?

Comment: BTW, removing the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\views\404.blade.php` resulted the whoops page.

Comment: So if you want to catch the `NotFoundHttpException` exception and you can do this from the `render` method in `App\Exceptions\Handler` class:

   `if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            throw $exception;
        } else {
            return parent::render($request, $exception);
        } `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174173/discussion-between-debiprasad-and-adre-astrian).

Answer (score 0):

Just to help someone in the feature.. I too experienced this issue not specifically after upgrade.

My environment set to local and app debug set to true but it still it shown me "500 error template" like we see in production. I like to see "whoops" error  with stack trace instead of that, since i'm in local environment.

Every possible solution suggested here and other forums didn't helped me out except the following which i did accidentally.

**Go to the same url in incognito mode and login to the app, it shown me the error page with stack trace.**

So I tried to replicate the issue again by clearing browser cache and reloading the url in the same incognito window, this time it shown me 500 error template.

Answer (score -2):

in **laravel 5.5** you have to check **APP_DEBUG, APP_LOG_LEVEL, APP_ENV**
in your **.env** file should be like below

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

and your config\app.php like below

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

Comment: Logging Configuration (`log` and `log_level`) has nothing to do with this issue. These features were also available in Laravel 5.4 (added in 5.2). As I had written before, I already have `APP_DEBUG=true`.